# Flutter: How can I enable scrolling for syncfusion chart while also having PanAndZoomBehaviour enabled?

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion

I'm using synfusion charts https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts
for my project so far they have great feature but when I try to scroll from it doesn't register the gesture when `PanAndZoomBehaviour` is enabled. And from there support page I found out that it is done purposefully, so how can I `override` the gesture for this chart so that I can enable scrolling.

I'm using `SingleChildScrollView` to scroll in another page.

code,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:practice2/models/heart_rate.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';

class HeartRateNormalChart extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
      child: SfCartesianChart(
          primaryXAxis: DateTimeAxis(dateFormat: DateFormat('MMM'),),
          primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(opposedPosition: true),
          zoomPanBehavior: ZoomPanBehavior(enablePinching: true),
          tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior(
            enable: true,
            header: 'Heart Rate (bpm)',
          ),
          series: <ChartSeries>[
            ScatterSeries(
              animationDuration: 1500,
              pointColorMapper: (heart, _) {
                if (heart.bpm < 60) {
                  return Color(0xffFF6262);
                } else {
                  return Color(0xff110E6B);
                }
              },
              dataSource: <HeartRate>[
                HeartRate(month: DateTime(2020, DateTime.february, 1), bpm: 70),
                HeartRate(month: DateTime(2020, DateTime.july, 12), bpm: 72),
                HeartRate(month: DateTime(2020, DateTime.august, 15), bpm: 55),
                HeartRate(
                    month: DateTime(2020, DateTime.november, 24), bpm: 65),
                HeartRate(
                    month: DateTime(2020, DateTime.december, 31), bpm: 80),
              ],
              markerSettings:
                  MarkerSettings(height: width * 0.04, width: width * 0.04),
              xValueMapper: (heart, _) => heart.month,
              yValueMapper: (heart, _) => heart.bpm.ceil(),
              enableTooltip: true,
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/zoom-pan link.

Answer (score 0):

The scrolling gesture is prohibited purposefully while user interactions are enabled in the following scenarios:

1. Crosshair or trackball enabled with a single tap as activation mode
2. Zooming or panning enabled with modes other than the selection zooming

As of now, this is our default behavior of the charts and we already logged feedback for this feature request. We are not able to provide a specific timeline for this since this is not on our planned list, but it will come in any of our upcoming releases. For more information, you can follow this [incident](https://www.syncfusion.com/support/directtrac/incidents/322671).